# Procfile for Heroku Java EE

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, heroku, procfile

I'm trying to deploy my Java EE backend application on Heroku, but I'm not sure what I need to put in my Procfile. I am following the tutorial, but when I try to deploy (locally) with : `heroku local` or `heroku local web` it fails.

I tried `web: java -jar target/muffinmap-backend.jar`, but I don't have a .jar file anywhere (it seems) and I get the error: `Error: Unable to access jarfile target/muffinmap-backend.jar`.

I have a war file, but I don't believe I should use that (at least not the same way as above) since when I try  `web: java -jar target/muffinmap-backend.war` I get `no main manifest attribute, in target/muffinmap-backend.war` which is understandable since it is not a .jar file.

So, now I'm not sure how I can fix this, I'm starting to doubt if it's even possible.

If there is more context needed just comment and I'll try to add it.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this guide to deploying WAR files on Heroku https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/war-deployment

It answers your question exactly. There are several ways to deploy WAR files to Heroku. You probably want to [include webapp-runner](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-webapp-runner) if you are deploying with Git. But you can also deploy the WAR file directly, which does not require a `Procfile`.

If you really need JEE features, you'll need to use something like Wildfly Swarm. But if you only need a Servlet container, webapp-runner is the way to go.